# How can I remove this button?CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working on the following site:

[link](http://www.altradona.ro/lenjerie-sexy/rochii-sexy.html)

I have put a clearer picture to understand what I want to remove.

http://i57.tinypic.com/344biah.jpg

How can I remove that particular button?

I have tried the following code but another button disappears.

```
.products-grid .button-container
{
display:none;
}
```

If you use this code, the button disappears along with the "add to cart" button. I just want what I have circled in the picture.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dont you have acces to the html templates? If it should not display at all, remove it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work:

```
.products-grid .regular .button-container
{
    display:none;
}
```